# Oracle SQL -- Count (*) where value is used multiple times, need to include NULL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to include results where some Problem Types are shared by multiple ID's and may contain a NULL on one but not on the other. Example: `EPISY_EMS` has a Problem Type of `Client Relations` and so does `EPISY_EPISYS`. The `EMS product` has a count of `10` and the `EPISYS product` has a count of `0` but doesn't display at all in the results, how can I get that to show as `0` or `Null`?

```
Select c.Product_id as [Product ID], b.DESCR as [Product Descr], 
       a.RC_SS_IND as [Self-Service Available], a.RC_SHORT_DESCR as [Problem Type],
       COUNT(*) as [Count]
From PS_RC_CASE c
JOIN PS_RC_PROBTYPE_TBL a on c.PROBLEM_TYPE = a.PROBLEM_TYPE 
                         AND c.Product_ID = a.Product_ID
JOIN PS_PROD_ITEM b on c.PRODUCT_ID = b.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE b.EFF_STATUS = 'A'
AND c.Creation_Date > '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000'
AND a.RC_SS_IND = 'Y'
AND a.RC_SHORT_DESCR in ('Client Relations', 'Implementation', 'General Ledger')
AND C.Product_ID in ('EPISY_CHOICE', 'EPISY_CKIMRT', 'EPISY_COLDOCTK', 'EPISY_EMS')
GROUP BY a.RC_SHORT_DESCR, a.PRODUCT_ID, 
         b.DESCR, a.RC_SS_IND, 
         b.product_id, c.PRODUCT_ID
Order By b.DESCR asc
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Please show sample data, expected output and current output, ideally as a SQLFiddle.

Comment: Is hard to say without sample data or expected output, but you probably should check `LEFT JOIN` and  `COALESCE`

Comment: Are you sure you're using Oracle? (Doesn't that code look more like SQL Server?)

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: @jarlh But I see all the field from the `SELECT` on the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, perhaps they are (and some other columns as well). When written in different order, it is not obvious.